# Workflow Approval - Add to Calendar

Tags: workflow, calendar, approval

I built a vacation request approval workflow and I am wondering if there is a way that once a request is approved that it will automatically be triggered to add to the group calendar.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add more step to your workflow.
After the validation (approval of your item) create a new item to your calendar with value of your request (date .... )

Comment: Can you elaborate on this more? Is that something you would have to do in SharePoint Designer?

Comment: yes, if you have Develop your "vacation request approval workflow" with SharePoint Designer, use it to Update your workflow